# Do while loop in Raptor

Tags: raptor

I would like to create a **do-while** loop in Raptor like the one in the picture:

[image: do-while loop]

instead of the **while** loop typical of Raptor. I don't seem to be able to put any block between "Loop" node and condition node.
Isn't it possible or am I missing something?

Raptor version is 4.1.0.0001

Notes:

- I am perfectly aware that I can simulate any do while with a while (I think there's also a theorem demonstrating it)
- I am  not interested at all in workarounds
- I'm a teacher and I would like my teenagers pupils to see concepts represented the same way they think, without having to use workarounds (I mean if most languages has both a while and a do-while there has to be a reason)

Comment: While I'm not familiar with Raptor specifically, I will say that flowcharts don't really have a `do` or `while` loop - they're more like assembly-code in that you express it as an conditional jump back to a prior instruction.

Comment: I am not familiar with Raptor either, but `do{A} while {B}` is basically `while(true){ A; if (!B) break;}`

Comment: @qrsngky I edited my question to clarify. Anyway I do think that the use of break should be limited to situations in which is really (performance) needed, otherwise is the way of writing "bad" code.

Comment: @massi Using `break` has _absolutely zero_ bearing on the performance of compiled code.